# Iron Router updates

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a project in Meteorjs which uses iron:router package. The problem is that, after I have updated the Meteorjs project to 1.4, iron:router doesn't execute it's function. I tried a few workarounds such as reinstalling of package, followed also the updates of iron:router syntax, still no good. I will show a sample chunk of code.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('home_t', {});
    this.render('cover_t', {to: 'beforehead'});
    this.render('front_t', {to: 'front'});
}, {
  controller: 'BasicController',
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    document.title = "Bfash | Home";
    this.next();
  },
  name: 'home_r'
});

Router.route('/products', function () {
    this.render('products_t', {});
}, {
  controller: 'BasicController',
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    document.title = "Bfash | Products";
    this.next();
  },
  name: 'products_r'
});

Router.route('/item/:_id/:ownerid', function () {
    Session.set('itemid', this.params._id);
    Session.set('ownerid', this.params.ownerid);
    this.render('item_t', {});
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['users'])){
      this.render('chat_t', {to: 'chatmessages'});
    }
    //if IP address
    Meteor.call('mostview_products',this.params._id,function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log('added');
      }
    })
}, {
  controller: 'BasicController',
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    document.title = "Bfash | Item";
    this.next();
  },
  name: 'item_r'
});

Router.route('/store/:name/:ownerid/:categoryid', function () {
    Session.set('ownerid', this.params.ownerid);
    Session.set('categoryid', this.params.categoryid);
    this.render('category_t', {});

}, {
  controller: 'BasicController',
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    document.title = "Bfash | Category";
    this.next();
  },
  name: 'category_r'
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't execute its function?" Did you switch to imports? Are you doing `import { IronRouter } from 'meteor/iron:router';` Are you importing your routes?

Comment: I have just tried awhile ago via importing the templates just like this `import '../imports/UI/aboutUs.js';` . But it works.

Comment: What are the errors you see on console?

Comment: `Error: There are multiple templates named 'shippingdetails_t'. Each template needs a unique name.`. This is the error I've encountered so far.

Comment: That error seems to be quite self-explanatory - do you have multiple templates with clashing names?

Comment: No, they have separate names. I have checked it already. I should follow the new file structure in MeteorJS. And must properly import the iron:router package. Thanks.